# Is there a word for a location where there is no signal or means of digital communication?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, slang

Is there a word or slang word that can be used to describe somewhere that is no signal or means of digital communication?   (i.e **Off the Grid**)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [dead zone](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dead%20zone) at Merriam Webster, defined as

> an area where cell phone reception is very poor or unavailable.

[Oxford dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dead_zone) says it more in terms we wanna hear:

> A place where it is not possible to receive a mobile phone or radio signal.

Comment: Do you have anymore?

Comment: Not at the moment. But I say *I'm in some hinterland* when I wanna suggest that it's a place with no comforts.